# Where are all the network-bridges coming from, ifconfig shows me?

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, network-bridge

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

As I'm a developer, I have [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) and [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) installed

If I enter in a terminal:

```
$ ifconfig
```

I got  a long list of network bridges.

```
br-2fdf26d8ad11: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.240.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.255.255


br-3097f1941dd7: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.32.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.47.255


br-604e362c8abb: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.28.255.255


br-6bec4010864a: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255

br-729cfdd5c2dd: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.48.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.16628.63.255


br-72c49f160076: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255

br-765c8f8c1edf: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255


br-7b6ec7d56aec: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255


br-9392c09745cd: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255


br-97685d1968fe: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.26.255.255

br-9b033123127c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255

br-bc2ff863085c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.96.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.111.255

br-bcc4b1218247: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255


br-d7d1dd0718f3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.80.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.95.255


br-dd4949ff923c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.25.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.25.255.255


br-de108e80ee4d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255

br-e37000236cd8: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255

br-ec26f968abd4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255


br-fa80bcc7af95: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255

enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)


lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>

vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.101.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.22.101.255

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 192.168.2.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
```

I'm not sure, where they all come from.

My problem is, that, if I want to use a public network (train, airports and so on), they normally run on 172.xx -> normally it's already used by a bridge, so I first have to bring it down and then delete it, as described in my [blog](https://joergi77.wordpress.com/2019/09/06/deutsche-bahn-docker-und-wifi-ice-and-vpn/)

```
sudo ip link set br-bcc4b1218247 down
sudo brctl delbr br-bcc4b1218247
```

I also read, that if you use the Ubuntu Network Manager, they can all come back.

I was trying to understand, where they come from but I haven't understood it yet really.

Comment: Docker tends to make a lot of bridges sometimes if you let it.  Those *sound* and *look* a lot like Docker-created bridges, but Vagrant could be at fault too

Comment: are they needed? and: does it make sense to allow docker to make bridges?
and how can i stop docker doing it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't really stop Docker or Vagrant from making bridges; the bridges are used to 'bridge' containers and virtual envs to your internet in a way that lets them have network connectivity.  Both Docker and Vagrant tend to do this (VBox creates vboxnet interfaces that act as the bridges but once created doesn't create more), and there's really no way to truly shut the functionality off without recoding how the vagrant systems and docker containers are brought up within their compose / config files.

Comment: can we change the ip and netmask of these bridges, they collided with my internal network @ThomasWard

Comment: @Windwalker thats entirely dependent on the config used to spawn them.  Docker compose files for instance let you designate the IP ranges for its bridges if you know what you are doing.  Dont know about Vagrant.  Thats a separate question post however.